# JQuery Mobile popup dialog flickers and re-positioned in a wrong place

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, popup, flicker

In my html, I have the below link to show popup dialog.

```
<h2 class="modest-size-chart">
    <a data-role="none" data-rel="popup" href="#sample_length_size_chart_popup" class="btn_size_chart">Size Chart</a>
</h2>
<div data-role="popup" id="sample_length_size_chart_popup" data-overlay-theme="b">
    ...
</div>
```

After click "Size Chart" from the page, popup dialog with id "sample_length_size_chart_popup" is shown. The default position of the dialog is in the center of the mobile screen.

When scrolling up/down the page, the popup will be moved up/down together with page. It's expected.

However, at some times (especially, the popup dialog is hidden and shown again), the popup dialog will be flickered and re-positioned at the center of the screen.

I don't want the re-position, it should be in the same position related to the page. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Set popup position to be relative to a specific element, adding:

```
data-position-to="#fixedElement"
```

to `<div data-role="popup" ... >`. This way the popup should always open near `#fixedElement`. You must use a `:visible` element, positioned according to your needs.

Comment: So, it should work with 'data-position-to="origin"', right? but no luck.

Comment: No, `origin` [is the default](http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/#option-positionTo), which I think positions the popup at window center

Comment: Thx for your comments. I have tried your suggestion, still no luck. I think `data-position-to=""` only works for the initial position. But the issue is popup dialog will be flickered and re-positioned in the center of the screen again during scrolling.

Comment: Again, based on the issue, I think there might be some event to invoke the popup dialog to render itself. But refer to the manual, for popup dialog, there are only 3 events, popupbeforeposition, popupafteropen, popupafterclose. None of them will invoke its render. Any idea for it?

Comment: Have you tried using [reposition](http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/#method-reposition) API method?

Comment: Sga, could you please go to this question -   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34806351/why-the-top-value-of-popup-dialog-is-changed-after-popupbeforeposition-event   ? Thx so much!