# Why the top value of popup dialog is changed after popupbeforeposition event

Tags: events, popup

I want my popup dialog to show at the top of the screen at each time, so, i add the logic in JS as follows.

```
$( "#dress_length_size_chart_popup" ).on({
    popupbeforeposition: function () {
        var f = document.getElementById('dress_length_size_chart_popup-popup');
        f.style.top = ** +'px';
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Although, the top is set in the callback function of `popupbeforeposition`, the value will be changed again, and my settings are overridden. (what happened here??)

If I move the logic to other callback function of `popupafteropen`. It will work.

However, when I scroll the page, only `popupbeforeposition` but not  `popupafteropen` will be called. So, the top setting is still lost.

So, the questions are

1. What is happened after `popupbeforeposition` to make the top value changed?
2. How I can catch the event to make my top setting work?

thanks!

Comment: I created an example to replicate your problem, but for me `popupafteropen` is called every time I open the popup

Comment: Yes, `popupafteropen` is called every time when you open a popup. But, when you scroll up/down the page, the popup is not closed. It's just render again, In this case, `popupafteropen` will not be called.

Comment: So, I guess the logic should be placed in event popupbeforeposition. But still not work event though I set the x,y values. `ui.x = 0; ui.y =0;`. Do you know what's the meaning of x,y of options of attr "open"? From the manual, they are the coordinates where the popup is to be displayed.  But, are they related to page, window or some selector?

Comment: `x` and `y` are relative to current view